# HPLIP does not launch on Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: hp, hplip

I installed the official apt version with all available packages

```
hplip
hplip-doc
hplip-data
hplip-gui
```

but it doesn't launch from GUI.

From terminal, I get like this:

```
hp-setup
error: Unable to locate models.dat file

HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 0.0.0)
Printer/Fax Setup Utility ver. 9.0

Copyright (c) 2001-18 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

(Note: Defaults for each question are maked with a '*'. Press <enter> to accept the default.)


Using connection type: usb

error: No device selected/specified or that supports this functionality.
```

Indeed, I don't have a USB-connected printer, but I do have a LAN-connected one.

The version offered for download from HP does not even install, because it has an unsatisfiable dependency.

Comment: If you run it from the terminal, do you get any output or does it silently fail?

Comment: Please see my edit to the OP

Comment: What is your printer model?

Comment: HP Officejet Pro 6830

Comment: The version of HPLIP from the Ubuntu repo still doesn't work, but there is a fix for the dependency issue of the version offered by the HP website. See this thread: https://answers.launchpad.net/hplip/+question/691141